# Silverlight with Extjs

Tags: silverlight, extjs

I haven't worked with extJS and Silverlight. Considering a requirement that I have to look into - is there a way to host Silverlight applications in extJS. 
   I checked out the Sencha forums, but did not find any direction.

Hope any one of you might have dealt with this issue earlier ?

Regards

Comment: What exactly do you mean by combining SL and ExtJs? Do you wan to run SL client application in the same web page as ExtJs or is it about sharing back end?

Comment: SL controls should get/set data via extJS, since the application architecture only exposes services, which are consumed by the extJS clients. The current SL control has to be integrated with this.

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible. We ended up using SL backend with WCF + EF, but using pure ExtJs on the front end - seems much more portable and future-proof

Comment: Can the xap file be just hosted like a flex control from via extJS?

Comment: I don't know. Sorry. We decided to go different route :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ext-JS is a JavaScript framework that allows you to create HTML pages dynamically. Silverlight is a plugin that embeds interactive content, packaged as a XAP, within an HTML document. This embedding is achieved via the HTML `object` tag.

You can certainly use Ext-JS to dynamically add `object` tags to pages and dynamically load XAP files. So I would say the answer is, yes, you can host Silverlight content using ExtJS.